# EXCEL Max value for multple time/date intervals

Tags: excel, date

I have an excel file as per the image attached
[image: Excel Data]

The date range in column D spans several days ie. there is also data for 10/08/2016; 10/09/2016, ect...

I am trying to get the maximum value in columnC for each 15 minute interval in column D.

eg:

10/08/2016  00:00 - 00:15  --  0
  10/08/2016  00:16 - 00:30  --  25
  10/08/2016  00:31 - 00:45  --  13

and so forth until the end of the file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make a unique list of dates and use `{=MAX(IF())}`. You could wrap the `{=MAX(IF())}` in some logic to determine if the date is an interval of 15 mins and then you wouldn't need to make a list of uniques. Assuming this list will grow, I'm not sure this is the most efficient/maintainable solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the 15 minute intervals.  To do this, I put the Date/Time Start values in column F starting in F2 (I assumed row 1 is a header row).  In cell F2 is this formula: `=FLOOR(MIN(D:D),15/1440)` and in cell F3 and copied down is this formula: `=IF(F2="","",IF(F2+TIME(0,15,0)>MAX(D:D),"",F2+TIME(0,15,0)))`

Then I put Date/Time End values in column G starting in G2 (because row 1 is a header row).  In cell G2 and copied down is this formula: `=IF(F2="","",F2+TIME(0,15,0))`

Now you can get your maximum per interval.  To do this, I put Max Interval Value results in column H starting in H2 using this formula copied down: `=IF(F2="","",MAX(INDEX(($D$2:$D$11001>=F2)*($D$2:$D$11001<G2)*$C$2:$C$11001,)))`

Adjust columns to suit your needs, and adjust the ranges (`$D$2:$D$11001` and `$C$2:$C$11001`) to suit your actual data.

Comment: I have not personally checked the implementation. The method/ logic is correct though.  I have implemented a similar solution. The trick is to 1stly generate yhe 15minute intervals. Once these are available it then becomes trivial to search for yhe maximum within each interval